# IWbemClassObject::Next yields VT_NULL types when they are not. What does this mean?

Tags: c++, wmi

I'm using Microsoft WMI to connect to a WMI namespace for a third-party hardware API.
All the initialization works fine. I get COM up and running, and I get connected to the WMI namespace. But when I call IWbemClassObject::Next to enumerate the class members, the members which are strings are returned as the type VT_NULL. The next function looks like this:

```
HRESULT Next(
  [in]             LONG lFlags,
  [out]            BSTR *pstrName,
  [out]            VARIANT *pVal,
  [out, optional]  CIMTYPE *pvtType,
  [out, optional]  LONG *plFlavor
);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa391453(v=vs.85).aspx

VARIANT is a "varying variable" type which can hold just about any built-in C++ type. It's type enumerator says VT_NULL, but in my head the class members should have been of type BSTR. So, what gives? Does it mean I have to query the types with WQL instead?

My goal is to create, modify and delete instances of classes, and their members. The WMI namespace is a proprietary one for custom hardware.

Comment: It is pretty common for WMI providers to just not implement a property.  You can tell by getting a null.  Contact the driver vendor for support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you read the comment on the `pVal` parameter?

> The method calls VariantInit on this
>   `VARIANT`, so the caller should ensure
>   that the `VARIANT` is not active prior
>   to the call.

And did you read the remarks?

> If the underlying type of the property
>   is an object path, date or time, or
>   another special type, then the
>   returned type does not contain enough
>   information. The caller must examine
>   the [CIMTYPE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa386469.aspx) for the specified
>   property, and determine if the
>   property is an object reference, date
>   or time, or another special type.

That CIMTYPE is obtained via the `pvtType` parameter, where the comment explicitly mentions the `VT_NULL` possibility:

> It is possible that the value of this
>   property can be a VT_NULL VARIANT

Comment: A million thanks to you sir. I thought the pvtType value was the same as the VARIANT::vt type enum. Everything works now.